# How to split data in a double groupby dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe, there are two index columns for it- 'date' and 'con'

```
In [28]: df = pd.read_csv('~/futures_min_all.csv')

In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
            open   close    high     low     tvr    oi  vol  ticker      date     tme con
0         2854.0  2850.0  2854.0  2850.0  5696.0  1226    2  MA1506  20140618   93000  MA
1         2854.0  2854.0  2854.0  2854.0  5698.0  1228    2  MA1506  20140618   93100  MA
2         2854.0  2854.0  2854.0  2854.0     0.0  1228    0  MA1506  20140618   93200  MA
3         2854.0  2854.0  2854.0  2854.0     0.0  1228    0  MA1506  20140618   93300  MA
4         2854.0  2851.0  2854.0  2851.0  5698.0  1228    2  MA1506  20140618   93400  MA
...          ...     ...     ...     ...     ...   ...  ...     ...       ...     ...  ..
27277818  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0     0.0     0    0  PM2105  20201223  145600  PM
27277819  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0     0.0     0    0  PM2105  20201223  145700  PM
27277820  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0     0.0     0    0  PM2105  20201223  145800  PM
27277821  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0     0.0     0    0  PM2105  20201223  145900  PM
27277822  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0  2359.0     0.0     0    0  PM2105  20201223  150000  PM
```

for each con, the date range is different.

```
In [30]: df.groupby(['con']).apply(lambda x: set(x['date']))
Out[30]: 
con
A     {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
AG    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
AL    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
AP    {20181008, 20181009, 20181010, 20181011, 20181...
AU    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
                            ...                        
WH    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
WR    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
Y     {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
ZC    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
ZN    {20160512, 20160513, 20160516, 20160517, 20160...
Length: 68, dtype: object
```

I want to split the dataframe into two part:

foremost 70% and last 30%

let me explain:

for con == 'IC', the 'date' range is [20200101 - 20201230] (about 365 days)

the foremost 70% of IC will be about [20200101 - 20200820]

for con == 'NI', the 'date' range maybe  [20200801-20201230]

in foremost 70%, rows of 'NI' will only keep 'date' in [20200801-20201020]

ps. i think the head(0.7 *len(df)) method may not solve this. becasue, i want the 70% of set(date), instead of total 70% of df

i think there must be some elegant method i can use to split the raw df into what i want, can you help on this?

Comment: Do you need solution without sorting? Like `df1 = (df.groupby('con',group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.head(int(len(x) * -.7))),reset_index(drop=True))` ?

Comment: @jezrael, i need sort, and i think it not just head can slove this, becasue, i want the 70% of set(date), instead of total 70% of df

Comment: you can take only two columns, con and date, sort_values and drop duplicates,  then groupby con, take the first 70% date, assign a label, then left join the origin df, with the label, you can split the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is modified solution for first 70% of unique rows, if order is not important change `pd.unique` to `set`s:

```
f = lambda x: x.head(int(len(pd.unique(x['Date'])) * -.7))
df1 = df.groupby('con',group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Last filter all not matched rows:

```
df2 = df[~df.index.isin(df1.index)]
```

Comment: thanks jezrael.  you provided me a good idea.  i think the correct code is: train_ratio = 0.7
is_df = df.groupby('con',group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[x['date'] <= x['date'].unique()[int(len(x['date'].unique()) * train_ratio)]])#.reset_index(drop=True)
os_df = df[~df.index.isin(is_df.index)]